# Two DB2 copies running at the same time

Tags: db2, windows-server-2008-r2, db2-luw

Is it possible to have two DB2 copies running concurrently? According to IBM, it is possible, but they don't say how.

I'm running on a Windows server 2008 r2.

First and default one's DB2 version is V9.7.400.
The second one that I want to add will be 11.1.0.

I can see both copies and I know they run, but I can't get them to run at the same time.

[DB2 copies with instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC8TI.png)

One of them is running, because I can check from the application. When I try to start the other data studio lunched the command, but keeps hanging.

When I try to create new database on the second copy, I get an error:[Error from creating database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jauMC.png)

Comment: Define "can't get them to run at the same time". Make sure the two instances use different ports.

Comment: One copy has DB2 control center. the other doesn't. which ever copy is the default one, the other doesn't work or connect.I did, one runs on the 50000, the other on 50001

Comment: `db2start` is a Windows command, not an SQL statement; it must be run from the "DB2 Command Window" (or whatever the name is -- don't have a Windows system handy to verify).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have more than one Versions of DB2 running you have to install both versions of the product and have an instance for each installation. 
During the installation choose "Install New".

It is well described [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0008099.html).

Comment: I did, but they can't get both copies to run at the same time. one copy has DB2 control center where I can manage it, the other doesn't have. Even Data studio is buggy, and doesn't even run.

Comment: DB2 Control Center only comes with the old versions. Since DB2 10.5 is no longer part of the client and Data Studio is the new GUI (or Data Server Manager). You can run both instances if you run db2start from the admin user of each instance (will be different ones). The Data Studio problem might be another (separate ) question....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any chance, I'll try Data server Manager, if it can manage both